# How do you use get_context_data with TemplateView in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AboutView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['dahl_books'] = Books.objects.filter(author="Dahl')
```

When I try to access dahl_books in my template like this:

```
{% for book in dahl_books %}
```

`dahl_books` is not available in the template context, even though the Books QuerySet returned a non-zero number of books. ....am I doing something wrong in either my template or in `get_context_data`?

Comment: This question was so extremely helpful, I wish I could vote it up a hundred times... I've been searching for ways to display re-defined get_context_data to the template, but had such a hard time finding it... thanks so much! (And I disagree with the close vote -- it's very much a question).

Comment: I found this new feature interesting: http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/05/19/context.html

Comment: I agree with @TimS. except probably just upvote 10 times since that's about how many posts I've looked at trying to figure out how to access my context variable without a clear answer.

Comment: Good question. I know SO flagged it for being vague but I think your question is how to add in context variables for a TemplateView in Django. It's more straightforward in a regular View class with a get method but what if you just want to use TemplateView? Anyways, good question.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I can't test it, but I bet you need

```
return context
```

at the end of `get_context_data` :)

Comment: I have a follow up, can I declore context as a class variable instead of local and returning it?

Comment: You will have to implement its use as a class variable but you can get context data however you want. Just realize that django looks for get_context_data so you'll have to override how django is looking for it in your get and post methods.